# How can I specify that a sub-regular expression should take precedence over adjacent sub-regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Suppose I want to match the following regular expression (matching e.g. `https://user:passwd@localhost:8080`), but want to get as much context around the matched substring as possible:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,10}://[^/\\s:@]{3,32}:[^/\\s:@]{3,32}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62})*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?
```

If I use eager matching for the context, e.g. `(.{0,25})`, then it will possible consume some of the characters that could be matched by `\w{3,10}`. Conversely, if I use lazy matching, e.g. `(.{0,25}?)`, then I will get no context at all:

```
>>> re.search('(.{0,25})([a-zA-Z]{3,10}://[^/\\s:@]{3,32}:[^/\\s:@]{3,32}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62})*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?)(.{0,25})', 'XXXXhttps://user:passwd@localhost:8080XXX').groups()
('XXXXht', 'tps://user:passwd@localhost:8080', 'XXX')
```

In the above example, I'd want `'ht'` to be part of the matched URL, so that group 1 would be:

`'https://user:passwd@localhost:8080'`

How can I specify eager matching for the context, but say that a regular expression should take precedence over neighbouring regular expressions and match as much as possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Can you include expected sample output? From the regex's point of view, `.` and `\w` are both equally valid ways to match all the characters `ABC`, so it's as if you had written `30 * 'X'` instead.

Comment: @jtbandes - Please check my updated question with much better examples.

Comment: Why do you want "context", as opposed to taking the start/end indices of the match object (m.start()/m.end()) ?

Comment: @jtbandes - you are absolutely right. I can't believe I didn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to update your regular expression to include "context" (not well-defined in your example), it seems easier to use the [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects)'s [`.start()/end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) methods to get the indices in the original string to which the match corresponds. Then you can manipulate those indices as desired to read some characters before/after the match.

Note that if you want to get the start/end index of a specific capture group inside the pattern, you can use `.start(group_number)`.

Comment: I used the `match` object's `span()` method to get the indicies.